# import ra.admin.admin could not be resolved django

Tags: django

I am having issues using the ra framework in django, I am using vs code, python 3.8.10, each time I try to import the ra framework there is a yellow line. what do I do to resolve this

Comment: install it in your virtual environment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did install it in a virtual env, but the same thing keeps happening